# put and get function missing from HashMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have a HashMap created in Java which has String as key and a custom class as value defined as follows:

```
HashMap<String,xyz> test = new HashMap<String,xyz>();
```

Class definition of xyz is:

```
public class xyz {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;

    xyz(String a,  String b,  String c ){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Now, when I am trying to retrieve values from hashMap I cannot use get method. Code used is as follows:

```
xyz temp = test.get("a"); // This is not working
```

However, if I create hashmap with just string as key and value I am getting get mehtod. Any help would be appreciated as to why this is happening and what can I do.

I hava java version "1.8.0_172" and my I am using Netbeans 8.2

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: How did you store the value you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: http://tpcg.io/f4GcWp Works for me.

Comment: Are you importing `java.util.HashMap`? Have you imported a different `HashMap` class? Do you have another class on the same package called `HashMap`?

Comment: Post a small but complete program that demonstrates your problem, it will help us debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestHashMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,xyz> test = new HashMap<String,xyz>();
    xyz x = new xyz("a", "b","c");
    test.put("a", x);
    System.out.println(test.get("a"));

}
```

}

absolutely, it can run well. and it come out the result

```
xyz@53d8d10a
```